# Shared data in app groups between mac app and safari extension return nil

Tags: swift3, safari-extension

I have a MacOS app which shares some data with a Safari Extension. Im not sure what im doing wrong, but when i run my Safari extension, it just returns nil.
Here is the code i use

```
//in my main viewcontroller
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)") {
        userDefaults.set("---" as AnyObject, forKey: "distance")
        userDefaults.set("---" as AnyObject, forKey: "altitude")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
}

//in my Safari Extension
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)") {
        print(userDefaults.string(forKey: "distance"))
        print(userDefaults.string(forKey: "altitude"))
```

}

I've also tried to change the suiteName to "group.com.company.project", but it still returns nil.

Comment: Did you remember to add the apps-group capability for the app and the extension?

Comment: Yes i did. Starting with, I forgot it and then i got an error, but now the extension just returns nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a name such as .group (ie: ABC4343DEV.group)

Comment: That did it! I get my values, but i still get this message from the console: "2017-05-27 10:05:15.001020+0200 myExtension[5794:334369] [User Defaults] Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x6080000feb80> (Domain: ABC4343DEV.group, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null)): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd
Optional("---")
Optional("---")". Should i worry about that?

Comment: That Apple's internal msg, do not worry about that